# How to delete all files and directories with an exception

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a few files and directories, *(all directories contain files)*:

```
C:\ABC
│   file1.txt
│
├───folder1
│       oneormorefiles.ext
│
├───folder2
│       somemorefiles.ext
│
└───logs
        aaa-test-01.log
        b-test-a-02.log
        cc-test-03.log
```

I want to delete all of the directories and the files they contain, but wish to keep `C:\abc\logs` and all of its files.

I have tried:

```
PUSHD "c:\logs" && rd /s/q "c:\abc" 2>nul
```

but this is deleting files in `C:\abc\logs` as well, *(I want to avoid that)*.

Thanks

Comment: So is `c:\abc\logs` a folder or a file. And what is `c\logs`? Your question is very unclear. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, enter `RD /?` or `RMDIR /?` at the prompt, then read the output. After doing so, you may want to consider your use of options, for instance, `/S`.

Comment: @RishiKesh Pathak I don't know the answer, but optionally you can always `copy` or `move` `c:\ABC\logs\*.log` and then `rd` or `rmdir` the entire tree of directories.

Comment: On cmd line `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir :C\ABC /B ^| findstr /VI "\\logs" ') do @echo %~aA|find "d" &&(rd /S /Q "%~fA")||(del "%~fA")`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest this as a possibile alternative to using `FOR` loop and/or a mixture of `DEL` and `RD`:

```bat
MD "%TEMP%\$_.dummy"&&ROBOCOPY "%TEMP%\$_.dummy" "C:\abc" /E /XD logs /PURGE>NUL 2>&1&RD "%TEMP%\$_.dummy"
```

Comment: Nice one, particularly as it does not touch the `logs` folder, hence its attributes are preserved (at first glance I thought it deletes and recreates, which would lose attributes, but obviously I was wrong)...

Comment: @aschipfl, yes it preserves the attributes etc. I have used it before for this very reason. It is also quicker than performing several `RD` commands, each with an `IF` from a `FOR /D` or `FOR /F` loop with an additional `DEL` command and one or more `CD` or `PUSHD`/`POPD`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way:

```cmd
rem // Change to the target root directory:
pushd "C:\ABC" && (
    rem // Loop over all immediate sub-directories:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:D "*"') do (
        rem // Remove sub-directory tree unless name is `log`:
        if /I not "%%F" == "logs" rd /S /Q "%%F"
    )
    rem // Delete files located in the root directory:
    del /A /F /Q "*.*"
    rem // return to the original directory:
    popd
)
```